# Serialize in XmlElement list of XmlAttribute's

Tags: c#

I want to serialize a list of XmlAttribute's in a XmlElement.

### Some general info about the program:

It's a program where you can add `product's` with some attributes like the `name`, a `description`, and **some properties (height, width, brand, condition), but the user can choose how many he want to add (not a fixed number)**.

### Here is the class diagramm of the program:

[image]

### Here is the code of the `ManagerRoot class`:

```
[Serializable]
public class ManagerRoot
{
    [XmlElement("ProductRoot")]
    public ProductRoot ProductRoot = new ProductRoot();
}
```

### Here is the code of the `ProductRoot Class`:

```
[Serializable]
public class ProductRoot
{
    [XmlElement("Product")]
    public List<Product> ProductList { get; set; }

    private void addProduct()
    {
        //?
    }
}
```

### Here is the code of the `Product class`:

```
[Serializable]
public class Product
{
    [XmlIgnore]
    private string _header;
    [XmlAttribute("Header")]
    public string Header
    {
        get { return this._header; }
        set { this._header = value; }
    }

    [XmlIgnore]
    private string _description;
    [XmlAttribute("Description")]
    public string Description
    {
        get { return this._description; }
        set { this._description = value; }
    }

    [XmlIgnore]
    private string _link;
    [XmlAttribute("Link")]
    public string Link
    {
        get { return this._link; }
        set { this._link = value; }
    }

    [XmlIgnore]
    private List<string> _properties;
    [XmlAttribute("Properties")]
    public List<string> Properties
    {
        get
        {

        }
        set
        {

        }
    }

}
```

Now I don't know what i have to do with the `getter` and `setter` of the list inside the class. And how can I add a new `product` with a `name`, `description`, `link` & a `filled properties list`?

Comment: What do you mean by "add a new product"? Add to where? Why not just instantiate a new product object, set the properties and add ProductList of ProductRoot object. Is that what you are asking? Sorry, it's not clear to me  what your problem is exactly

Answer (score 0):

For collections you need to annotate the property with XmlArray and XmlArrayItem to define which is the contained item. Please follow the same ProductList pattern for all collection based properties.

namespace ConsoleApplication1
    {

```
[Serializable]
public class ProductRoot
{
    [XmlArray]
    [XmlArrayItem(ElementName = "Product", Type = typeof(Product))]
    public List<Product> ProductList { get; set; }
}

[Serializable]
public class Product
{
    [XmlIgnore]
    private string _header;
    [XmlAttribute("Header")]
    public string Header {
        get { return this._header; }
        set { this._header = value; }
    }

    [XmlIgnore]
    private string _description;
    [XmlAttribute("Description")]
    public string Description {
        get { return this._description; }
        set { this._description = value; }
    }

    [XmlIgnore]
    private string _link;
    [XmlAttribute("Link")]
    public string Link {
        get { return this._link; }
        set { this._link = value; }
    }

    [XmlIgnore]
    private List<string> _properties;
    [XmlAttribute("Properties")]
    public List<string> Properties { get; set; }
}

static class Program
{

    static void Main() {
        var productRoot = new ProductRoot();
        var products = new List<Product>();

        products.Add(new Product() { Description = "A", Properties = new List<string> { "PropA" } });
        products.Add(new Product() { Description = "B", Properties = new List<string> { "PropB" } });
        productRoot.ProductList = products;

        Test(productRoot);
    }

    static void Test<T>(T obj) {
        using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream()) {
            XmlSerializer s = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
            using (var stringWriter = new StringWriter()) {
                using (var writer = XmlWriter.Create(stringWriter)) {
                    s.Serialize(stringWriter, obj);
                }

                Console.WriteLine(stringWriter.ToString());
            }
        }
    }
}
```